# OOP - Creation of Class, iterating through an album of songs?

Tags: python, oop

I'm learning about OOP and I need some help with defining one of the methods under Album, specifically total_runtime.

Here's some code (verified, all correct) on the context of the question.

```
class Duration(object):
    def __init__(self, minutes, seconds):
        self.total_seconds = minutes * 60 + seconds
        self.minutes = int(self.total_seconds / 60)
        self.seconds = self.total_seconds % 60       
        
    def get_minutes(self):
        return self.minutes
    
    def get_seconds(self):
        return self.seconds

    def __str__(self):
        # returns the string representation of the Duration in "mm:ss" form.
        if len(str(self.minutes)) < 2:
            self.minutes = "0" + str(self.minutes)
        if len(str(self.seconds)) < 2:
            self.seconds = "0" + str(self.seconds)
        return str(self.minutes) + ":" + str(self.seconds)
    
    def __add__(self, duration):
        #Adds 2 durations together
        return Duration(self.minutes + duration.minutes, self.seconds + duration.seconds)

class Song(object):
    def __init__(self, artist, title, duration):
        self.artist = artist
        self.title = title
        self.duration = duration
    
    def get_artist(self):
        return self.artist
          
    def get_title(self):
        return self.title
        
    def get_duration(self):
        return self.duration
            
class Album(object):
    def __init__(self, artist, title):
        self.artist = artist
        self.title = title
        self.songs = list()

    def add_song(self, song):
        # Adds song (of class Song) to the album.
        self.songs.append(song)
```

I need some help with defining the property total_runtime(self) under class Album which is supposed to return the total runtime (of class Duration) of the album.

Here's what I have now. I tried iterating through the album to get the durations of all the songs. Somehow I'm getting an error which says that **add** is not defined.

```
def total_runtime(self):
        duration = (0,0)
        for song in self.songs:
            __add__(self, duration)
        return duration
```

Would really appreciate any help debugging! Thank you!

Comment: First try to create a loop where you print the duration of each `song`.

Comment: Like this?                                                                                                                   
def total_runtime(self):
        song_durations = ()
        for song in self.songs:
            song_durations += get_duration(song)
        return  __add__(duration, duration)                                                                                          It says that get_duration is not defined though

Comment: It seems to me that you're getting a little bit ahead of yourself. I recommend that you take a few steps back and start over with some of the basics of Python and its syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `__add__` as an attribute of the class, the `self` argument is the object you're calling from. It's implicitly moved into the arguments.

```
def total_runtime(self):
        duration = Duration(0,0)
        for song in self.songs:
            duration.__add__(song.get_duration())
        return duration
```

But really, `__add__` is more cleanly used with the plus operator:

```
def total_runtime(self):
        duration = Duration(0,0)
        for song in self.songs:
            duration += song.get_duration()
        return duration
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the input. I've tried these codes but I'm getting a TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "Duration") to tuple. Any idea how to convert duration to a "duration" (it's a tuple now?)? Thank you!

Comment: my bad, I forgot to make (0, 0) a `Duration` object

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you :)